# Can i copy exactly same character from league of legends?

Tags: game-mechanics, copyright

Lets say i will copy exactly same mechanic of a character from the game "league of legends"

or Copying puzzles from another games. But changed assets etc.

Is it illegal ?

Comment: This has essential been asked before with: [Is it legal to develop a game using other games skill names/flavor/mechanic?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/106219/is-it-legal-to-develop-a-game-using-other-games-skill-names-flavor-mechanic) (and related/linked questions). If you believe that your question is substantially different, please edit to make those difference clear. Also keep in mind that this community isn't a source of legal advice ("GDSE said I could" isn't likely to keep you from being sued) - if you need legal advice, please consult a legal professional.

Comment: Apart from legality, I think it's also worth asking whether this serves your goals and aspirations as a designer. Is this why you became a game creator, to copy someone else's work, instead of showing the world your own creativity? Is making an asset flip of a game/puzzle that already exists the fulfilling work you dream of? Or are there creative challenges you value more?